# Adding custom classes & JSPs to existing third party java web application

Tags: java, war

I have a requirement to add some custom classes and JSPs to an existing java web application. The custom classes must be in their own package, away from the existing java classes. The existing application is built on the struts framework.

I'm fairly new to all this and need guidance on the following:

1. Using Eclipse IDE, If I import the existing WAR file and libraries and unpack the WAR file, how do I compile new .java source files and add the .class files to the WAR?
2. The existing .class files are contained in a JAR. Do I need to create a JAR file containing the new .class files outside of eclipse and then add it to the same location as the existing .class JAR file i.e. WEB-INF/lib (there is no WEB-INF/lib/classes folder)
3. Adding the JSPs and amending the web.xml file should be fine but are there any pitfalls to look out for ?

   Any and all help greatly appreciated

Comment: If you post the class you want to add, it would be easier to give you a hint.

Comment: @ujulu The three classes are CustomerExtendAction, CustomerExtendRootBean, & CustomerExtendDataBean

Comment: Haven't meant the class names :-)

Comment: Ha!! I was wondering about that alright :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I import the existing WAR file
>   I don't advise you to import third party war file into Eclipse. Instead do the following:

1. Create a dynamic web application in Eclipse (See the screenshot below):
   [image]
2. Implement your custom classes and put them under the folder `Java Resources / src`
3. Put the JSPs under `WebContent / jsps` (you can choose any name you like)
4. Create a new directory in your file system (Windows / Unix ...) and copy the thirdparty war into it.
5. Unpack the war file using command line as:

   ```
   jar xvf mythirdparty.war
   ```
6. Copy your class files (they should be under `build / classes` folder; see screenshot) to `WEB-INF / classes` folder of the unpacked thirdparty war.
7. Copy the JSPs (folder `jsps`) to the root of the unpacked war.
8. Remove the the old war (of the thirdparty war) so that
9. Navigate to the root and pack again as:

   ```
   jar cvf thirdparty.war *
   ```

Comment: Thank you ujulu, I'll try it out on Monday, much obliged